# I use bootstrap for wordpress theme but my menu-item deosnt show in mobile view otherwise it has no problem

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

[screenshot for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sSW3.jpg)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgb(27, 23, 23);">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
        <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
    ) );
    ?>
```

Search
            
        
    
 use bootstrap for wordpress theme but my menu-item deosnt show in mobile view otherwise it has no problem

Comment: Have you linked Bootstrap JS in header after Bootstrap css

Comment: On mobile (**XS** screen sizes) the menu items should be collapsed and you only will see a button (because you using `navbar-expand-sm`). If all good, and you click that button, the menu should appear with an `slide-down` effect. Replace to `navbar-expand` if you want the `navbar` to be always expanded. Anyway, posting a screenshot of your issue will help too.

Comment: tnx ,as you said the button apear with slide down effect but my menue item wont show up.

Comment: i added a screenshot link above

Comment: Check your `wp_nav_menu()` method, what this method create? For the options I see, it appears to make the div with `class = "collapse navbar-collapse"` that you have already defined using a different attribute id. Use the browser inspector tool and check there is no redundant code created.

Comment: Tnx very much,it solved.by deliting this function 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', it show correctly.